# Does golang have the plan for supporting set datastructure?

Tags: dictionary, go, set

This feature can be implemented with 'map'.

```
countrySet := map[string]bool{
  "US": true,
  "JP": true, 
  "KR": true,
}
```

But to ease the eyes of readers, 'set' is a necessary data structure.

```
countrySet := set[string]{"US", "JP", "KR"}
```

Does golang have the plan for supporting syntax like this?

Comment: No, Go will never support this, as it doesn't make sense. There's no way to know what the value should be without providing it. But in future, if you want to know what's planned for Go, or suggest your own ideas, just visit the [Go issue tracker](https://github.com/golang/go).

Comment: Also consider: If you know the value is always true, then using a `bool` is entirely unnecessary. You can instead use a map as a only list of arbitrary keys by using a `map[string]struct{}`. It's a bit cumbersome to read and set, but it conveys the intention more clearly, since a `struct{}` cannot contain any value at all. This is as close as you can come to a `map[string]nil`.

Comment: Thank you @Flimzy, In my machine-learning scenario, 'set' is a very high frequency data structure, so I try to find a simple way to init a set. BTW, In such scenario, people always compare with python.

Comment: Having a `set` primitive may or may not make sense--although Go is unlikely to adopt one. Having a `set` library probably does make sense (and does exist, as provided in an answer). In any case, your proposed `map` initialization syntax does not make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know about such plans.

What you may do to ease the initialization:

**Use a one-letter `bool` constant:**

```
const t = true
countrySet := map[string]bool{"US": t, "JP": t, "KR": t}
```

**Use a loop to add the keys, so you only need to list the keys:**

```
countrySet := map[string]bool{}
for _, v := range []string{"US", "JP", "KR"} {
    countrySet[v] = true
}
```

This is only profitable if you have more elements.

**But you can always create a helper function:**

```
func createSet(es ...string) map[string]bool {
    m := map[string]bool{}
    for _, v := range es {
        m[v] = true
    }
    return m
}
```

And then using it:

```
countrySet := createSet("US", "JP", "KR")
```

Comment: Thank you for good solutions @icza. But I think built-in data-structure is more efficient way. VS Python ( T_T )

Comment: @cnby: More efficient how?

Answer (score 6):

The plan is not to support everything in the Go standard library. The plan is to encourage open source, independently developed packages. For example, one of many,

> [package sets](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/sets)
>
> `import "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/sets"`
>
> Package sets has auto-generated set types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @peterSO. I'm using a wrapper like this.

Comment: [`github.com/soroushj/menge`](https://github.com/soroushj/menge) is another one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `map[string]bool` is a good option. Another option is
`map[string]struct{}`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   s := map[string]struct{}{
      "JP": {}, "KR": {}, "US": {},
   }
   s["UA"] = struct{}{}
   if _, ok := s["UA"]; ok {
      println("ok")
   }
   fmt.Println(s)
}
```

It's marginally better than `bool`, as the values take up zero bytes versus one byte, but it's a little more awkward to work with. Another option is `fstest.MapFS`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "testing/fstest"
)

func main() {
   s := fstest.MapFS{"JP": nil, "KR": nil, "US": nil}
   s["UA"] = nil
   if _, ok := s["UA"]; ok {
      println("ok")
   }
   a, e := s.Glob("U*")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   fmt.Println(a) // [UA US]
}
```

This is neat because you can do pattern matching on the Set items.

https://golang.org/pkg/testing/fstest

Answer (score 2):

Now with the Go 1.18+ generics feature, there are great packages that implement a generic Set data structure! You may use them for any [comparable](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_constraints) type of items.

Take a look at this one: https://github.com/amit7itz/goset

```
package main

import "github.com/amit7itz/goset"

func main() {
   s := goset.NewSet("a", "b", "c", "d")
   s2 := goset.NewSet("c", "d", "e", "f")
   fmt.Println(s.Intersection(s2)) // Set[string]{"c", "d"}
   fmt.Println(s.Union(s2)) // Set[string]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
}
```